# datepicker date range: max date's min date = start day + 1 day

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Using the jQuery UI's datepicker date range, how can I customize the default functionality so that when the start date is selected the min date for the end date is not the same as start date, but start day + 1 day.

I know I could replace the 'selectedDate' with bunch of `getDate()` and `setDate()` functions called on the start date `val()`, but I was wondering if there might be a intended feature supported by the datepicker. Something like `selectedDate +1 day`, but obviously I already tried that and that does not work.

Bellow is the code I am currently using that sets the option for `minDate` of `#to` to selected date in `#from`

```
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">

<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate ); 
                //how to change this so that the minDate is selectedDate + 1 day? 
            }
        });
        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this

```
var actualDate = new Date(selectedDate);
var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+1);
```

```js
$(function() {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
              
                //$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate ); 
                //how to change this so that the minDate is selectedDate + 1 day? 
            var actualDate = new Date(selectedDate);
            var newDate = new Date(actualDate.getFullYear(), actualDate.getMonth(), actualDate.getDate()+1);
       
            $("#to").datepicker("option","minDate", newDate)
            },
          
        });
        $( "#to" ).datepicker({
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">
```

Comment: ok so then theres no intended feature by jQuery UI. Thank you.